# How to get a specific parameter matrix (tensor) of a model by its name in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, parameters, pytorch

I have trained my model in pytorch. Now I want to extract a specific parameters tensor by its name (not all tensors). How can I do that?

```
print(myModel.parameters)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<bound method Module.parameters of ANN(
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=4, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=4, out_features=1, bias=True)
)>
```

For example, I only want to get ***fc1.weight*** and ***fc1.bias***.

Comment: `myModel.parameters` is the `parameters` method of your model. You probably meant to do `myModel.parameters()`. Even so, Ivan's answer is the proper way to access specific parameters of your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access sub-modules with the dot notation directly, while [`parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters) returns a iterator over all tensors *without* providing keys:

```
>>> myModel.fc1.weight
>>> myModel.fc1.bias
```